# Using strings containing integers as table keys

Tags: lua, lua-table

I realize this is usually not a great practice, but how would I use a string containing an integer (e.g. `"7"`) as a table key? For example:

```
local myTable = {
  "1" = "Foo",
  "2" = "Bar"
}
```

If memory serves from reading the Lua manual back in the day, that should be possible with some special syntax, but what I've written above is a syntax error.

Comment: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.7

Comment: `local myTable = { "Foo", "Bar" }` or `{ [1] = "Foo", [2] = "Bar" }` – in your example, you don't even have any integers.

Comment: You're right, I phrased my question incorrectly. What I meant to say is that I want strings that hold integers as keys (e.g. an associative array). I don't want integers as simple array indicies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
local myTable = {
  ["1"] = "Foo",
  ["2"] = "Bar"
}
```

Because the keys are not valid identifiers, you can't use the syntax sugar form.